# Can a horse owned by a Jewish owner run in any of the Triple Crown races?

Tags: shabbat, animals, melacha-creative-work

All of the "Triple Crown" horse races (Kentucky Derby, Preakness, and Belmont) occur on Shabbat.

If the horse's owner is Jewish, (I just learned that American Pharaoh's owner is Jewish; I didn't know that!) wouldn't he be prohibited from having the horse running the horse on Shabbat, as there is a commandment that the animals have to rest, also?

For the animal to be able to run in these races, would the owner have to sell the horse to a Gentile for Shabbat only, and then buy him back?

Concerns within this question (there may be others that I haven't thought of):

1 - Is the animal doing *melacha* by running in the race? Perhaps, running per se may not be a *melacha* as this is what horses normally do. But, as he is in a competition, perhaps this is *melacha*. What is considered *melacha* and *menucha* for an animal (animals are required to "rest"; not only to just refrain from *melacha*.)

2 - By winning a race (perhaps, even by losing, as well), the owner gains monetary reward. It is received after Shabbat, most likely. But, would he be profiting from the horse's *melacha*, or even if not *melacha* specifically, is the owner violating Shabbat from the mere fact that his horse is in a race?

Comment: running is not a melacha...

Comment: @DoubleAA when the pasuk says "lo ta'aseh kol melacha etc." and then lists animals does it mean that the animal is forbidden from performing one of the 39 melachot or that the owner is forbidden from performing one of the 39 through the use of the animal? If the latter, and someone could show that horse racing is somehow a melacha, then using a horse to do that, whether or not the running, itself, is a melacha, would be forbidden.

Comment: @Danno horse racing is not a melacha, although I assume there are problems here, such as שכר שבת...

Comment: @wfb I don't necessarily disagree but I am looking for the nafka mina between the 2 interpretations of the pasuk. There ARE (to my simple mind) other problems but I am just curious about this approach.

Comment: Causing a jockey to ride on it (horse riding is an issue drebbanan.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Probably hard to make it deoraita, but carrying the jockey and associated stuff around is probably hotza-a derabanan.

Comment: @ClintEastwood I just thought of that. Can you further support and source that? The jockey is a Gentile.

Comment: @DoubleAA it wouldn't be considered mechamer? Or does we say chai nose was atzmo

Comment: @IsaacMoses Ya, that's the best I can think of. Hard to call a race track a Reshut Harabbim.

Comment: @Mefaresh See Isaac's comment

Comment: @DoubleAA A race track is not reshut harabim? The public comes to the track to watch the race. Belmont, in particular, allows the public to visit the track and paddocks at any time.

Comment: @DanF The race track is pretty thoroughly surrounded by fences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24629/discussion-between-danf-and-double-aa).